# Does libtorch leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, libtorch

I am using pytorch c++ library (libtorch) in my project. When using valgrind it seems that some memory is not free properly.

**Main.cpp:**

```
int main() {
    // Do somenting with libtorch here...
    std::cout << "end of main" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Valgrind command:**
`valgrind --leak-check=full ./myapp`

**Valgrind output:**

```
==385785== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==385785== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL d, by Julian Seward et al.
==385785== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==385785== Command: ./btai
==385785== 
==385785== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x48f5000, 0x17ecd000) (defined)
end of main
==385785== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==385785==    at 0x8181EE8: torch::jit::deregisterOperator(c10::FunctionSchema const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x8361AB5: torch::jit::(anonymous namespace)::RegistrationListener::onOperatorDeregistered(c10::OperatorHandle const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x583ACAC: c10::Dispatcher::deregisterDef_(c10::OperatorHandle const&, c10::OperatorName const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x58733D4: c10::RegisterOperators::~RegisterOperators() (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x1827F15D: __cxa_finalize (cxa_finalize.c:83)
==385785==    by 0x574C6E2: ??? (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x4011F5A: _dl_fini (dl-fini.c:138)
==385785==    by 0x1827EA26: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:108)
==385785==    by 0x1827EBDF: exit (exit.c:139)
==385785==    by 0x1825C0B9: (below main) (libc-start.c:342)
==385785== 
==385785== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==385785==    at 0x81820FD: torch::jit::deregisterOperator(c10::FunctionSchema const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x8361AB5: torch::jit::(anonymous namespace)::RegistrationListener::onOperatorDeregistered(c10::OperatorHandle const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x583ACAC: c10::Dispatcher::deregisterDef_(c10::OperatorHandle const&, c10::OperatorName const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x58733D4: c10::RegisterOperators::~RegisterOperators() (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x1827F15D: __cxa_finalize (cxa_finalize.c:83)
==385785==    by 0x574C6E2: ??? (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x4011F5A: _dl_fini (dl-fini.c:138)
==385785==    by 0x1827EA26: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:108)
==385785==    by 0x1827EBDF: exit (exit.c:139)
==385785==    by 0x1825C0B9: (below main) (libc-start.c:342)
==385785== 
==385785== 
==385785== HEAP SUMMARY:
==385785==     in use at exit: 724,686 bytes in 11,651 blocks
==385785==   total heap usage: 481,322 allocs, 469,671 frees, 59,519,540 bytes allocated
==385785== 
==385785== 256 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 11,294 of 11,400
==385785==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==385785==    by 0xB7CB7A3: mm_account_ptr_by_tid..0 (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0xB7CAE79: mkl_serv_malloc (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x9AB5B86: mkl_serv_domain_get_max_threads (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x5791278: at::init_num_threads() (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x8E1C68B: at::native::(anonymous namespace)::min_all_kernel_impl(at::Tensor&, at::Tensor const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x5B19042: at::native::min(at::Tensor const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x633CD3B: c10::impl::wrap_kernel_functor_unboxed_<c10::impl::detail::WrapFunctionIntoFunctor_<c10::CompileTimeFunctionPointer<at::Tensor (at::Tensor const&), &at::(anonymous namespace)::(anonymous namespace)::wrapper__min>, at::Tensor, c10::guts::typelist::typelist<at::Tensor const&> >, at::Tensor (at::Tensor const&)>::call(c10::OperatorKernel*, c10::DispatchKeySet, at::Tensor const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x6154390: at::Tensor c10::Dispatcher::redispatch<at::Tensor, at::Tensor const&>(c10::TypedOperatorHandle<at::Tensor (at::Tensor const&)> const&, c10::DispatchKeySet, at::Tensor const&) const [clone .isra.165] (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x615DA3E: at::redispatch::min(c10::DispatchKeySet, at::Tensor const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x7AC1310: torch::autograd::VariableType::(anonymous namespace)::min(c10::DispatchKeySet, at::Tensor const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x7AC17EE: c10::impl::wrap_kernel_functor_unboxed_<c10::impl::detail::WrapFunctionIntoFunctor_<c10::CompileTimeFunctionPointer<at::Tensor (c10::DispatchKeySet, at::Tensor const&), &torch::autograd::VariableType::(anonymous namespace)::min>, at::Tensor, c10::guts::typelist::typelist<c10::DispatchKeySet, at::Tensor const&> >, at::Tensor (c10::DispatchKeySet, at::Tensor const&)>::call(c10::OperatorKernel*, c10::DispatchKeySet, at::Tensor const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785== 
==385785== 69,664 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 11,400 of 11,400
==385785==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==385785==    by 0xB7CBA27: mm_account_ptr_by_tid..0 (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0xB7CAE79: mkl_serv_malloc (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x9AB5B86: mkl_serv_domain_get_max_threads (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x5791278: at::init_num_threads() (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x8E1C68B: at::native::(anonymous namespace)::min_all_kernel_impl(at::Tensor&, at::Tensor const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x5B19042: at::native::min(at::Tensor const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x633CD3B: c10::impl::wrap_kernel_functor_unboxed_<c10::impl::detail::WrapFunctionIntoFunctor_<c10::CompileTimeFunctionPointer<at::Tensor (at::Tensor const&), &at::(anonymous namespace)::(anonymous namespace)::wrapper__min>, at::Tensor, c10::guts::typelist::typelist<at::Tensor const&> >, at::Tensor (at::Tensor const&)>::call(c10::OperatorKernel*, c10::DispatchKeySet, at::Tensor const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x6154390: at::Tensor c10::Dispatcher::redispatch<at::Tensor, at::Tensor const&>(c10::TypedOperatorHandle<at::Tensor (at::Tensor const&)> const&, c10::DispatchKeySet, at::Tensor const&) const [clone .isra.165] (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x615DA3E: at::redispatch::min(c10::DispatchKeySet, at::Tensor const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x7AC1310: torch::autograd::VariableType::(anonymous namespace)::min(c10::DispatchKeySet, at::Tensor const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785==    by 0x7AC17EE: c10::impl::wrap_kernel_functor_unboxed_<c10::impl::detail::WrapFunctionIntoFunctor_<c10::CompileTimeFunctionPointer<at::Tensor (c10::DispatchKeySet, at::Tensor const&), &torch::autograd::VariableType::(anonymous namespace)::min>, at::Tensor, c10::guts::typelist::typelist<c10::DispatchKeySet, at::Tensor const&> >, at::Tensor (c10::DispatchKeySet, at::Tensor const&)>::call(c10::OperatorKernel*, c10::DispatchKeySet, at::Tensor const&) (in /home/tmac3/Desktop/Branching_Time_Active_Inference/libs/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
==385785== 
==385785== LEAK SUMMARY:
==385785==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==385785==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==385785==      possibly lost: 69,920 bytes in 2 blocks
==385785==    still reachable: 654,766 bytes in 11,649 blocks
==385785==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==385785==                         stdstring          : 359,526 bytes in 4,879 blocks
==385785==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==385785== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==385785== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==385785== 
==385785== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==385785== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==385785== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

As you can see there are valgrind errors and memory leaks after the main function. They seems to come from libtorch, where does those errors comes from, and how to get rid of them?

Comment: *"// Do something with libtorch here..."* That seems the interesting part to look into :-/

Comment: The project is quiet big, I can't show everything. The code mostly create tensor en apply operation onto them (no backpropagation is used).

Comment: Create minimal code (init/deinit) using libtorch, then progressively add stuff until you got the issue.

Comment: It would be better if you specify your libtorch version when you show your research.

Comment: Note that valgrind is only reporting "possible" leaks, not definite leaks.  So it is entirely possible (even likely) that libtorch isn't leaking, at least not in any way that is going to cause problems in practice.  The warnings about "conditional jump or move depends on unitialized values" are a bit more concerning, as they likely indicate the presence of undefined behavior, but that's a separate issue from memory leaks

Comment: That a good point. Also, "conditional jump" only appears after the main, i.e., when the memory is being cleaned up but not during the program execution. I did not have time to produce the minimal code example yet since I am working on more urgent issues.

Answer (score 1):

As far as we know, the libTorch `torch::jit::Module` leaks memory on mobile: You cannot release memory of a `torch::jit::Module` after loading a TorchCcript file.

Answer (score 0):

We met the same leak problem at exactly the same location at::init_num_threads(). It seems that the leak may happen at some libtorch code, but finally goes to at::init_num_threads().
We hope you have made some process in this issue.

Comment: I am wondering wether the problem is coming from valgrind which might not be able to track memory in perfectly in multi-threaded application... (pure hypothesis)

Comment: I added mkl_free_buffers() at end of libtorch inference. It solves problem above, but new possible leak occured....
```
==50790==    by 0x59C0821: ideep::tensor::reorder_to(ideep::tensor&, ideep::attr_t const&) const (in /opt/e2e-streamingASR/runtime/server/x86/fc_base/libtorch-src/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)

```